# Cypher: what is the use of YIELD?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to understand the use of YIELD in Cypher requests.

For example:

```
CALL db.labels() YIELD label
WHERE label CONTAINS 'User'
RETURN count(label) AS numLabels
```

But I don't understand why I have to use this and when.
Can someone explain me what is the use and when do I have to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/#query-call-introduction) for `CALL` and `YIELD`.

Here are a couple of snippets from the docs:

> Most procedures return a stream of records with a fixed set of result
> fields, similar to how running a Cypher query returns a stream of
> records. The `YIELD` sub-clause is used to explicitly select which of
> the available result fields are returned as newly-bound variables from
> the procedure call to the user or for further processing by the
> remaining query. Thus, in order to be able to use `YIELD`, the names
> (and types) of the output parameters need be known in advance. Each
> yielded result field may optionally be renamed using aliasing (i.e.
> resultFieldName `AS` newName). All new variables bound by a procedure
> call are added to the set of variables already bound in the current
> scope. It is an error if a procedure call tries to rebind a previously
> bound variable (i.e. a procedure call cannot shadow a variable that
> was previously bound in the current scope).

> Inside a larger query, the records returned from a procedure call with
> an explicit YIELD may be further filtered using a `WHERE` sub-clause
> followed by a predicate (similar to `WITH` …​ `WHERE` …​).
>
> If the called procedure declares at least one result field, `YIELD` may
> generally not be omitted. However `YIELD` may always be omitted in a
> standalone procedure call. In this case, all result fields are yielded
> as newly-bound variables from the procedure call to the user.